# A song called "Lu Hua"

Tags: meaning, culture

I recently heard a live performance of an amazing song by a Chinese woman in the United States. She said the title of the song is "Lu Hua", and I was able to find a version on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywgm4BeoR8c

Can anyone tell me more about this song? Like what it means, who the original artist is, and if there is a high-quality soundtrack available anywhere (like Spotify).

Comment: It is probably 芦花 and you can google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

芦花 is the correct song name. 崔晓琳 is the original artist, but the artist 雷佳 version is more popular.
You can listen it here: https://y.qq.com/n/yqq/song/000lL1ly0LYiE6.html.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find a version on Spotify and many live performances on YouTube using the Chinese spelling. Love this song!